# Expansion in stored csname of restatable theorem

Tags: theorems, counters, expansion, thmtools

Thinking about [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/694950/208544), I'd like to use thmtools' `restatable` environment to store theorems with a number in the csname. That way one can loop through them at the end of the document to restate each one. My issue is that the way thmtools stores this csname seems to prevent expansion of commands within.

Here's an example that works. `\somecmd` steps through a counter and stores its argument in `cmd-1`, `cmd-2`, etc.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{foo}

\newcommand{\somecmd}[1]{%
    \stepcounter{foo}%
    \expandafter\def\csname cmd-\thefoo\endcsname{#1}%
}

\begin{document}
\somecmd{A}
\somecmd{B}
\somecmd{C}

\UseName{cmd-1}
\UseName{cmd-2}
\UseName{cmd-3}

\ExpandArgs{c}\ShowCommand{cmd-1}
\ExpandArgs{c}\ShowCommand{cmd-2}
\end{document}
```

The output is `A B C` and the log shows

```
> \cmd-1=macro:
->A.
<argument> \cmd-1 
                  
l.19 \ExpandArgs{c}\ShowCommand{cmd-1}
                                      

> \cmd-2=macro:
->B.
<argument> \cmd-2 
                  
l.20 \ExpandArgs{c}\ShowCommand{cmd-2}
```

as expected.

Now here's a try with `restatable` where `\declaretheoremx` works like `\declaretheorem` but also defines an environment `saved<thmname>` that stores its contents in a command `thm-<num>`. Since the environment grabs its contents we need to use the `+b` argspec.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kantlipsum,amsthm,thmtools}

\newcounter{savedthmcount}

\newcommand{\declaretheoremx}[2][]{
    \declaretheorem[#1]{#2}
    \NewDocumentEnvironment{saved#2}{+b}{%
        \stepcounter{savedthmcount}%
        \begin{restatable}{#2}{thm-\thesavedthmcount}
        ##1
        \end{restatable}
        }{}
    }

\declaretheoremx{theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{savedtheorem}
\kant[2][1]
\end{savedtheorem}

\begin{savedtheorem}
\kant[3][1]
\end{savedtheorem}

\UseName{thm-1}*
\UseName{thm-2}*

\ExpandArgs{c}\ShowCommand{thm-1}
\ExpandArgs{c}\ShowCommand{thm-2}
\end{document}
```

[image: thms]

Everything works as expected except that each command `thm-<num>` is just the last theorem called. In the log we get

```
> \thm-1=macro:
->\@ifstar {\thmt@thisistheonefalse \csname thmt@stored@thm-\thesavedthmcount \
endcsname }{\thmt@thisistheonetrue \csname thmt@stored@thm-\thesavedthmcount \e
ndcsname }.
<argument> \thm-1 
                  
l.31 \ExpandArgs{c}\ShowCommand{thm-1}
                                      

> \thm-2=macro:
->\@ifstar {\thmt@thisistheonefalse \csname thmt@stored@thm-\thesavedthmcount \
endcsname }{\thmt@thisistheonetrue \csname thmt@stored@thm-\thesavedthmcount \e
ndcsname }.
<argument> \thm-2 
                  
l.32 \ExpandArgs{c}\ShowCommand{thm-2}
```

which makes it seem like the stored csname is the literal string `thmt@stored@thm-\thesavedthmcount` instead of `thmt@stored@thm-thm-1`, `thmt@stored@thm-thm-2`, etc.

What is going wrong here? The definition of the `restatable` environment in `thm-restate.sty` is somewhat complicated but I don't see anything that would "protect" the argument from expansion.

**Edit:** [This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26016/208544) seems to work but I'd still like to know specifically what's going wrong without this trick.

Comment: The example on page 7 of the thrmtools manual also loads `thm-restate`.

Comment: @JohnKormylo `thm-restate` is automatically loaded by `thmtools`

Comment: your thm-1 macro is obviously not fully expanded, it contains commands like `\@ifstar` and `\thesavedthmcount` and what this commands do will depend on their meaning when you use the command. `\ExpandArgs{nnx}\begin{restatable}{#2}{thm-\thesavedthmcount}` should work.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks. Sorry to ask a follow-up in the comments but if I wanted to allow the optional argument for restatable like `\begin{restatable}[##1]{#2}{thm-\thesavedthmcount}`, what would be the argument of `\ExpandArgs`? For example `\ExpandArgs{nxnx}` doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the `\edef` trick mentioned in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26016/208544).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kantlipsum,amsthm,thmtools}

\newcounter{savedthmcount}

\newcommand{\declaretheoremx}[2][]{
    \declaretheorem[#1]{#2}
    \NewDocumentEnvironment{saved#2}{O{}+b}{%
        \stepcounter{savedthmcount}%
        \edef\temp{%
            \noexpand\begin{restatable}[##1]{#2}{thm-\thesavedthmcount}%
          }%
        \temp
        ##2
        \end{restatable}
        }{}
    }

\declaretheoremx{theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{savedtheorem}
\kant[1][1]
\end{savedtheorem}

\begin{savedtheorem}
\kant[3][1]
\end{savedtheorem}

\UseName{thm-1}*
\UseName{thm-2}*

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your problem, but this code runs fine.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{thmtools, thm-restate}
\declaretheorem{theorem}

\newcounter{foo}
%\renewcommand{\thefoo}{\alph{foo}}

\begin{document}

\stepcounter{foo}
\begin{restatable}[Euclid]{theorem}{test\thefoo}
\label{thm:euclid}%
For every prime $p$, there is a prime $p’>p$.
In particular, the list of primes,
\begin{equation}\label{eq:1}
2,3,5,7,\dots
\end{equation}
is infinite.
\end{restatable}

\stepcounter{foo}
\begin{restatable}[Euclid]{theorem}{test\thefoo}
\label{thm:euclid}%
Every integer greater than 1 has a unique prime decomposition.
\end{restatable}

\setcounter{foo}{0}
\loop\ifnum\value{foo}<2
  \stepcounter{foo}%
  \csname test\thefoo\endcsname*
\repeat

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, however I don't think this answers my question of what's wrong with packaging this in a new environment. The goal is not to do the counter stepping and naming manually

Comment: The manual did mention that some counters are automatically reset (page 17).  It could also be a local vs. global issue.

Comment: By default only `equation` is reset, so this should not affect my issue

Answer (score 0):

`restatable` doesn't perform expansion in its second argument (the label) and you want to expand it. The recent `\ExpandArgs` facility is your friend.

I made a few changes to the definition of `\declaretheoremx`:

1. `\NewDocumentCommand` is more powerful;
2. the counter is allocated as part of it;
3. a trailing optional argument is added (default is the same as the main argument) for the prefix.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kantlipsum,amsthm,thmtools}

\NewDocumentCommand{\declaretheoremx}{O{}mO{#2}}{%
  \newcounter{saved#2}%
  \declaretheorem[#1]{#2}%
  \NewDocumentEnvironment{saved#2}{+b}{%
    \stepcounter{saved#2}%
    \ExpandArgs{nne}\begin{restatable}{#2}{#3-\UseName{thesaved#2}}
    ##1
    \end{restatable}%
  }{}%
}

\declaretheoremx{theorem}[thm]

\begin{document}

\section{Main text}

First a theorem

\begin{savedtheorem}
\kant[2][1]
\end{savedtheorem}

Another theorem

\begin{savedtheorem}
\kant[3][1]
\end{savedtheorem}

\section{The statements}

\UseName{thm-1}*
\UseName{thm-2}*

\end{document}
```

[image]