# How to update a specific package from ctan

Tags: expl3, xparse, ctan, update

In the answer to this [thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/474095/172923) it is advised to use the package `xparse` released 05/03/2019 or later. I've been trying to update this specific package, but without success.

First I updated all the packages with the command

```
tlmgr update --all
```

hoping that this would automatically install the latest version of `xparse` (which is in the `l3packages` bundle). Unfortunately that didn't happen, since compiling the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\listfiles
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

the `log` file shows that I'm using the `xparse` version released on `2018-10-17`.

[image]

How can I force the update?

Comment: The best solution would be to wait for TeX live 2019 to be released or install the pretest version (if you can't wait for another few days: http://tug.org/texlive/, the current plan is to release TeX live 2019 on 2019-04-30). TeX live 2018 is frozen now and won't receive updates any more. (For background see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/107017/35864). If you must install `xparse` on your current frozen TeX live 2018, you need to install the package manually, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/117518/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73016/35864. (I would not recommend that.)

Comment: If you install the update manually, you are responsible to make sure to install all dependencies to avoid version conflicts. If you update `xparse` you probably also need to update all other `expl3` kernel packages.

Comment: I didn't know that it was only a matter of days till TeX live got updated. Btw, once the update is out, is there some line of code that I can type in the terminal to update it?

Comment: Well you are lucky you only want the update now. TeX live 2018 got frozen at the end of February (which explains why the March update of `xparse` is not in TeX live 2018) and then it needs a bit of time to ready the next release. In this case roughly until 2019-04-30. There is no officially advertised simple way to update TeX live 2018 to TeX live 2019. You just install TeX live 2019 (you don't have to uninstall TeX live 2018, the versions can coexist). See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/107017/35864 (apparently there are ways to upgrade, but they are not tested much...)

Comment: ensure you download the tds version this will cut installation errors down considerably http://mirrors.ctan.org/install/macros/latex/contrib/l3packages.tds.zip unpack it to the root of a tds (texmf) folder and your good to go with 2018

Answer (score 3):

To update a *specific* `<package>`, forcibly reinstall it using

```
tlmgr install --reinstall <package>
```

That should pull the latest version of the package from CTAN (or one of its mirrors).

Comment: But that won't fetch the package from a different version of TeX Live (which is what OP wants: 2020 `xparse` on TL'19)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik: Riiiight. I didn't read between the lines to note that he's wanting an up-to-date version from a later TeX Live version. I'll update my answer to be more comprehensive.