# TexLive Update to Individual Package Problem

Tags: packages

I am using the TexLive 2020 distribution, running on Ubuntu 20.04.2 via Windows Subsystem for Linux 1 (WSL1) on Windows 10, if that matters. I just noticed that the package `siunitx` has had a major update and I would like to try it out. I saw this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/488087/how-to-update-a-specific-package-from-ctan) and I tried running the command `tlmgr install --reinstall siunitx`. I have to do it using `sudo` and when I do it times out and says the following in the terminal.

```
/usr/local/texlive/2020/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr: TLPDB::from_file could not initialize from: http://mirror.utexas.edu/ctan/systems/texlive/tlnet/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb
/usr/local/texlive/2020/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr: Maybe the repository setting should be changed.
/usr/local/texlive/2020/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr: More info: https://tug.org/texlive/acquire.html
```

I also tried changing the mirror from the `utexas` one to `https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/` but I get a similar error.

```
/usr/local/texlive/2020/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr: TLPDB::from_file could not initialize from: https://ctan.math.illinois.edu//tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb
/usr/local/texlive/2020/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr: Maybe the repository setting should be changed.
/usr/local/texlive/2020/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr: More info: https://tug.org/texlive/acquire.html
```

Does anyone know what the problem might be? Or how I could fix it?

Comment: you can no longer update texlive 2020 via tlmgr the tlmgr infrastructure only supports one year at a time.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle isn't this error also related to the lets encrypt problem? tlmgr needs to download the data before it can complain that this is TL2020 and it is no longer supported

Comment: @David, the https (the latter) URL the OP is using here is using Lets encrypt and it is exactly the same error I got yesterday from that Mac. Perhaps the tlmgr maintainers should provide some better error messages

Comment: Also the first server does not even respond

Comment: Ah okay - I did not realize I was 'stuck' with 2020 and all its packages. I guess the answer then is to install a new distribution of TexLive. Thank you!